# Convert Between Percentages and Decimal

Tags: code-golf, number

<sup>I, uh....honestly can't believe we don't have this one yet.</sup>

## Challenge

Write two functions or programs that:

1. Convert from decimal to percentage
2. Convert from percentage to decimal

You may also write a single program that does both of the above.

## Format

Percentages *must* be taken and returned with a percent sign. (In many languages, this means they will be strings.) They may be integers or floating point numbers.

Decimals are just floating point numbers.

You do not need to handle rounding errors involving very large or very small floating point numbers.

In cases where the numbers are integers (such as 56.0) you may return `56`, `56.`, or `56.0`. (This is intended to make I/O more flexible.)

## Test Cases

```
    0.0% <-> 0.0
  100.0% <-> 1.0
   56.0% <-> 0.56
  123.0% <-> 1.23
  -11.0% <-> -0.11
-214.91% <-> -2.1491
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins. If you write two separate programs, add their sizes for your score.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the test cases correctly, they mandate that an input of `0.0` return both `0%` and `0.0%`. Which one is it?

Comment: Good point. I've updated to make it more clear that all numbers involved are floating point numbers.

Comment: I think we should just convert to percent and not back and forth. That makes the challenge unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Never mind that. It's good

Comment: Also, is writing a single program allowed. Another user did it, so I just want to know if that is allowed.

Comment: @ckjbgames Yes, you may write a single program or function that can handle both types of input

Comment: @musicman523 Kewl

Comment: Are we allowed to use 2 languages?

Comment: @ckjbgames You should use the same language for both parts of the problem; however, you may add another answer if you wish to answer in a different language

Comment: I'm downvoting because it's a very boring challenge. Nothing wrong about the challenge itself, other than that.

Comment: @isaacg That's fine, and you are of course entitled to that opinion. I made this challenge knowing it wouldn't be difficult, simply because I wanted to see the answers and it's easier for new PPCG members to get involved on easier questions. Think of it as a learning opportunity - go answer in a language you've never used before! Or go answer some harder challenges if you're still not convinced :)

Comment: @musicman523 upvote for your consideration on helping new PPCG users like me :)

Comment: @isaacg This challenge is quite difficult in a batch file as we don't have decimal multiplication, nor decimal division...

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 34+20=54

to Decimal

```
ToExpression@StringDrop[#,-1]/100&
```

to Percentage

```
ToString[100#]<>"%"&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

This one does both.

```python
lambda s:'%'in s and`float(s[:-1])/100`or`float(s)*100`+'%'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/dDoIwDIXv9xS9IQOVufKXQMKTIAkzSFyCG2G78ennxAjrVb/2nJN2edunVpmb2pubxes@CjANjahUYECocZhmLWxsuibFPrki54Ne/8Pk9OWzlzv7MNZACx0BX5QzHtHLr/eagMoqXGV5QCliSBkWrMadfchuO1rOyuoYZ/nu5gzxiGJY1EhJT8ikV5Dg39subjbBskplYYpl4j4)

## Single functions, score 27 + 28 = 55

### Decimal to percent, 27 bytes

```python
lambda s:`float(s)*100`+'%'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiEtJz@xRKNYU8vQwCBBW11V/X9JanFJsYKtQjSXAhCoG@gZqOtAmIYIpoGeqRlC2MgYxtY10DM0hHOM9AxNLA3VuWK5uNLyixQyFTLzFMDGW4EVFBRl5pUopGlkav4HAA)

### Percent to decimal, 28 bytes

```python
lambda s:`float(s[:-1])/100`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiEtJz@xRKM42krXMFZT39DAIOF/SWpxSbGCrUI0lwIQqBvoGaiq60DYQHkknqkZspSRMRJP19AQmWdkaKJnaaiqzhXLxZWWX6SQqZCZpwC2xwqsoqAoM69EIU0jU/M/AA)

Comment: Why do you need the backticks in the second snippet? Isn't returning as float allowed?

Comment: Percentages must be taken and returned with a percent sign.

Comment: @KarlNapf Yes, they do. But for `float(s[:-1])/100` you do not need a percent sign, and hence can be returned as a floating-point number.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

From percentage:

```
/L
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=L0w=&input=LTIxNC45MSU=)

To percentage:

```
*L+'%
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KkwrJyU=&input=LTIuMTQ5MQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 45 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to musicman523.

From decimal, to percent:

```
a->new Float(a.split("%")[0])/100
```

To percent, from decimal:

```
a->a*100+"%"
```

Comment: You sure the second function is valid Java?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I was surprised when I tried it out. Yes, it's valid Java.

Comment: @Okx would `new Float(...)` work in place of `Float.valueOf(...)`?

Comment: @musicman523 So it would. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 20 bytes

To percentages

```
'%',⍨100∘×
```

From percentages

```
.01×∘⍎¯1↓⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBHVVdZ1HvSsMDQwedcw4PJ0rHSimZ2B4eDqQ@6i379B6w0dtkx91LQKqVjDQMzbhSldQNzVVVQcA)

Comment: You can shorten the `0.01` to `.01`

Comment: `'%'~⍨⊢` can become `¯1↓⊢`

Comment: @KritixiLithos thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 10 + 10 = 20 bytes

Decimal to percentage:

```
*×100~'%'
```

Percentage to decimal:

```
*.chop/100
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>81</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```
def a(m):e=m.strip("%");f=float(e);return f/100if e!=m else str(f*100)+"%"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctBCsIwEIXhvaeIgcKMYpxQRGjJYQLOYKBJQxoXPX2MK@nyffwv7/W9prG1F4vyEHFiF81WS8igB42zOFlWX4FxLlw/JSm5W6Igis8uKl42Vj0HuXTFa/@0XEKq4EFbQxrx9N9EwwFuZJ6Po9jxl7Qv)

EDIT: Saved 4 bytes by removing some whitespace.
EDIT: Saved another 3 bytes by setting float(e) to a variable.

Comment: +1 for an extremely well-made PPCG answer. Also, removing some whitespace will save you some bytes.

Comment: Here's an even shorter Python 3.6 version: `def a(m):e=m.strip("%");f=float(e);return f"{f*100}%"if e!=m else.01*f`. Replace `f"{f*100}%"` with `str(f*100)+"%"` to make it <3.6 compatible. (The 3.6 version won't work on tio.run so use something like repl.it instead.)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>62 bytes</del> 61 bytes

Thanks @ckjbgames

```php
$i=readline();echo strstr($i,'%')?(float)$i/100:($i*100).'%';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVTJti1ITU3Iy81I1NK1TkzPyFYpLioBIQyVTR11VXdNeIy0nP7FEUyVT39DAwAoorAWkNfWActb//@saGuoZqAIA)

Comment: Remove the newline. That should help.

Comment: @ckjbgames Thanks for the tip!

Comment: PHP 7.1 `<?=$argn[-1]>'%'?($argn*100)."%":$argn/100;`

Comment: `<?=100*$argn."%";` and `<?=$argn/100;` should be the shortest way form the commandline with the `-F` option

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 16+19 = 35 bytes

Percent to decimal:

```
(/100).read.init
```

Decimal to percent:

```
(++"%").show.(*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 20+12=32 bytes

### To Decimal

```
p=>parseFloat(p)/100
```

### To Percentage

```
d=>d*100+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

From % to decimal

```
¨т/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0IqLTfr//@saGZroWRqqAgA)

And from decimal to %

```
т*'%«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YpOWuuqh1f//6xrpGZpYGgIA)

#### Explanations

```
¨т/
¨   # Cut of last character
 т/ # Divide by 100 (I know. Very creative)

 т*'%«
 т*    # Multiply by 100
   '%« # Append '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 + 5 = 10 bytes

% → number

```
ṖV÷ȷ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlhh7ef2G70//9/UwMDPQNVAA)

number → %

```
×ȷ2”%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9BPbjR41zFX9//@/qZ4BAA)

Full program only.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 15 + 4 = 19 bytes

Assuming that the values to be converted are stored in field A1

**Percentage to decimal**

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A1)
```

**Decimal to percentage**

```
=A1%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes + 27 bytes = 50 bytes

First program (% -> decimal)

```
float(input()[:-1])*.01
```

Second program (decimal -> %):

```
str(float(input())*100)+'%'
```

Rather similar to the other one. Pretty easy, too.

Comment: Write `two`....

Comment: @CalculatorFeline yeah

Comment: Does this convert back and forth between decimal and percent?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Need to do that

Comment: @NonlinearFruit How to best implement

Comment: I miss read, the spec asks for 2 programs. So you need a second one for decimal to percent. The current one should also print the result

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Done!

Comment: Your second program doesn't run: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`

Comment: @LyricLy Lemmeh fix

Comment: @LyricLy Done! There you go

Comment: If you are writing full programs, you will need to print your output. Maybe you should be testing your programs on a site such as [TIO](https://tio.run/#python3)

Comment: @musicman523 It was just the second one, which is now fixed.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by changing `0.01` to `.01`. You can also switch to Python 2 and save 7 bytes by removing `float()`, since `input()` will automatically read the number as a floating point number.

Comment: @musicman523 kewl

Comment: @musicman523 Is using 2 languages allowed?

Comment: @ckjbgames No need to double comment, I get notified for both.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda x:`float(x.strip('%'))*[100,.01]['%'in x]`+['%','']['%'in x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvNCgIhFEb3PcVFELVMvP0QDPQkJowRkjCjYi7s6c1ZtTrnO/Dlb32neOr@/uiLW58vB22a/ZJc5U19agmZM8qE2BvUWiqN1owdIjQ7HzaVjP1T96lAgOGGoMILkWTc6MBRq9t1I54psdMOcgmxgudB9B8)

Comment: This is a really clever answer. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
i=input()
print(float(i[:-1])/100if'%'in i else'%.2f%%'%(float(i)*100))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRCMtJz@xRCMz2krXMFZT39DAIDNNXVU9M08hUyE1pzhVXVXPKE1VVV0VplBTC6hGU/P/f10jPUMTS0MA)

Answer (score 0):

## **Haskell, <s>60</s> 42 bytes**

Decimal to percentage (21 bytes)

```
f x = show(x*100)++"%"
```

Percentage to decimal (21 bytes)

```
f x = read(init x)/100
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! As per [community consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/56433) submissions may not assume the input is present in a certain variable. Function submissions are allowed though, so you can fix your answer by prepending `f x=` or `\x->`.

Answer (score 0):

## ES6, 34 bytes

```
n=>1/n?n*100+'%':n.slice(0,-1)/100
```

(Now works with `0.0` and `0%`)

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/2ndAttmt/x8urh9yt/3/)

This works because `1/n` is `NaN` if a "%" is present and `NaN` is like `false`.

(`1/n` with `n = 0` is `Infinity` (not `NaN`) and `Infinity` is not considered `false` by JS)

Comment: But `!0` is also false... using `1/n` might work though.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original comment on why this works, `!NaN` is `true` not `false`.

Comment: Sorry, `!0` is true too of course. What was I thinking?

Comment: @Neil Thank you for your help, the new version is still 34 bytes, but now works with zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 77 bytes

```
^-?
$&00
\b%?$
00%$&
\.(..)
$1.
(....)\.(.*)%%
.$1$2
^(-?)0+\B|\B0+(%?)$
$1$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jck7CsMwEIThfs6hNVKMlh35Aa4EbnIJYZJAijQpQkrfXZHjZvn2n8/z@3rfq/jrrW4xw3VmKA/JDmbiOhT1qgGOiobGI1yCCNTRJWw@5mB9WfeyWu8lB4djqNXUBO2A9icbp/mM0wym4axpQCQPR1MSMXHUhe1NynHhDw) Link includes test cases. Requires and returns input with at least one digit before and after the decimal point. Explanation: The first stage inserts two leading zeros after any sign, while the second stage inserts two trailing zeros and a `%` sign before any `%` sign. (The `\b` is needed to stop the pattern matching twice for percentages.) The third stage then multiplies by 100. This results in the correct numerical value for floats converted into percentages, but percentages are now 10,000 times too big and now have a duplicated `%` sign, so the fourth stage corrects this. The final stage then trims leading and/or trailing zeros as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## perl 5: 24 bytes

**From % to decimal: 8 bytes** (7 + 1 for p flag)

```
$_/=100
```

*Usage:*

```
echo '-214.91%' | perl -pe '$_/=100'
```

*Output:*

```
-2.1491
```

**From decimal to %: 16 bytes** (15 + 1 for p flag)

```
$_*=100;$_.="%"
```

*Usage:*

```
echo -2.1491 | perl -pe '$_*=100;$_.="%"'
```

*Output:*

```
-214.91%
```

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), score 19

### Percent to decimal, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code_page)

```
-1⇆⊣f100⇆÷
```

#### Explanation

Take 56.0% for example.

```
-1⇆⊣f100⇆÷

               implicit input                               ["56.0%"]
-1             push -1                                      ["56.0%", -1]
  ⇆            switch "56.0%" and -1                        [-1, "56.0%"]
   ⊣           pop -1 and "56.0%" and push "56.0"           ["56.0"]
    f          pop "56.0" and push 56.0 (convert to float)  [56.0]
     100       push 100                                     [56.0, 100]
        ⇆      switch 56.0 and 100                          [100, 56.0]
         ÷     pop 100 and 56.0 and push 56.0 / 100         [0.56]
               implicit output                              []
```

### Decimal to percent, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code_page)

```
100×s'%⇆+
```

#### Explanation

Take 0.56 for example.

```
100×s'%⇆+

               implicitly take input and convert to float    [0.56]
100            push 100                                      [0.56, 100]
   ×           pop 0.56 and 100 and push 100 * 0.56          [56.0]
    s          pop 56.0 and push "56.0" (convert to string)  ["56.0"]
     '%        push "%"                                      ["56.0", "%"]
       ⇆       switch "56.0" and "%"                         ["%", "56.0"]
        +      pop "%" and "56.0" and push "56.0%"           ["56.0%"]
               implicit output                               []
```